# Given a list of numbers, return the products of all the elements in the list

Tags: python

I wrote a function called `compute_product_of_all_elements`. That gives a list of numbers, and the returns the products of all the elements in the list.

Notes: If any non-numeric values exist in the list, it returns 0

It gives the following error, I thought I had taken care of this instance?

> TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

```py
def compute_product_of_all_elements(arr):
    if arr == []:
        return 0
    for elem in arr:
        if elem == type(str):
            return 0
    accum = 1
    for elem in arr:
        accum *= elem
    return accum
```

Comment: What are you calling this function with?

Comment: Could you include the initial list of numbers in your post.

Comment: @ScootCork it is on the program website am training on, so whatever they are providing for the practice problems. I am not sure if that helps, or if I am able to tell what we are running the code on.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the first if statement and second if statement. Everything seems like good code.

```
def compute_product_of_all_elements(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    for elem in arr:
        if isinstance(elem, str):
            return 0
    accum = 1
    for elem in arr:
        accum *= elem
    return accum
```

Test:

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = ["test",2,3,4,5]
arr3 = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(compute_product_of_all_elements(arr1))
print(compute_product_of_all_elements(arr2))
print(compute_product_of_all_elements(arr3))
```

Output:

```
0
0
120
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code didn't didn't work is because of this:

```
if elem == type(str):
```

You need to change it to:

```
if type(elem) == str:
```

---

```
def compute_product_of_all_elements(arr):
    if arr == []:
        return 0
    for elem in arr:
        if type(elem) == str:
            return 0
    accum = 1
    for elem in arr:
        accum *= elem
    return accum
```

---

---

It would be better to use `isinstance()`:

```
def compute_product_of_all_elements(arr):
    if arr == []:
        return 0
    for elem in arr:
        if isinstance(elem, str):
            return 0
    accum = 1
    for elem in arr:
        accum *= elem
    return accum
```

#### UPDATE:

Here is my minimalist solution:

```
def compute_product_of_all_elements(arr):
    from math import prod
    if not arr or any(not isinstance(i,(int,float)) for i in arr):
        return 0
    return prod(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few comments.

Firstly, as other answers have correctly noted, your test for a string value is incorrect. You need to be doing `if type(elem) == str:` or `if isinstance(elem,str):`

However, more broadly, I don't think that you should be trying to entirely suppress the raising of an exception if the caller sends a string (just returning 0).  Rather, you should be **actively raising a `ValueError`** to say that this is not a valid input to the function.  You can then trap that in the caller if you want to handle the error more gracefully than simply aborting the program with a traceback.

For example:

```
def compute_product_of_all_elements(arr):
    for elem in arr:
        if isinstance(elem, str):
            raise ValueError("string isn't allowed")
    accum = 1
    for elem in arr:
        accum *= elem
    return accum 

try:
    print(compute_product_of_all_elements([10, "blah"]))
except ValueError as exc:
    print("it complained that {}".format(exc))
```

outputs:

```
it complained that string isn't allowed
```

The other comment is that you'll see that I have removed the testing for the special case of an empty list.  This means that if you do send an empty list, you will get the return value `1` (not `0`).  This is the logical thing to return as the product of an empty list, because it preserves the relationship that:

> (product of list A) * (product of list B) = product of (list A + list B)

Indeed, you will find for example that in NumPy, `numpy.product(an_empty_array)` gives value 1 for precisely this reason.

(Analogously the **sum** of an empty list should indeed be 0.)

Answer (score 0):

> If any non-numeric values exist in the list, return 0

You, and folks answering this question, misinterpreted this requirement as a `str` type test -- that isn't correct.  What if your array is:

```
[13, 56, None, 12, 147]
```

The `str` type test isn't going to save you.  Instead, we need to do something more like:

```
def compute_product_of_all_elements(array):
    if not array:  # deal with both array == [] and array is None
        return 0

    product = 1

    for element in array:
        if isinstance(element, (int, float)):  # how should complex fit in?
            product *= element
        else:
            return 0

    return product
```

We don't need separate loops, we can test and multiply in the same loop.